# www.phoneerror-x00059f.tech virus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I've recently been hit by what appears to be a virus on my phone. Whenever trying to access a web page, even just by following a link from a google search, I am redirected to a page with a pop up message that says:

"The page at www.phoneerror-x00059f.tech says:

WARNING!

Your Samsung Galaxy S7 phone is infected with a virus that can damage the battery!

The system has six viruses that cause serious damage to your battery and which must be immediately destroyed.

Do not close this page.

** If you exit you leave at our own risk **"

If I close this pop up message, the page behind it that appears to be a fake Google site still informing me of there being 6 viruses on my phone and wants me to follow the link marked "Destroy All Viruses", which no doubt will do just the opposite.

Does anybody know how to kill this thing? I have tried clearing the Cache Data for both Internet and Google, but to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Regards, Ben.

Comment: If you solved this question, can you approve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

All fixed it seems. Found another option to clear the data from Internet (I swear that option wasn't there earlier today), and that seems to have worked. Or for now at least. We shall see...

Comment: In addition clear out the browser cache

Comment: Don't forget to check your apps list in order to find if there is not a malware installed.